# How can I iframe a website such that popups do not happen?

Tags: html

I want to embed

```
http://www.yocast.tv/embed.php?s=dx123&width=1340&height=540&domain=cricketembed.com
```

in an iframe. However, that site produces too many popups. I want to put that in the iframe such that no popups happens. Is that possible... This is a third party domain and I have no control on it.

Comment: You answered your question yourself: `This is a third party domain and I have no control on it`.

Comment: FYI, Windows Defender blocks this website as Malicious.

Comment: I am not looking for software to block. I am looking for ways to block it through codes.. so that when I iframe sites like this the popups never show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `sandbox` attribute to the iframe. (Note: [limited support](http://caniuse.com/#search=sandbox)).

```
<iframe ... sandbox="">
```

Leaving it as an empty string will disable most features, you can selectively add them using a space separated list of acceptable features. See [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) for available features.

You do not want to include `allow-popups` in that list. Firefox does not support `allow-popups` so you might not want to `allow-scripts` either.